# SQL query to search all tables and databases data for a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search

Is there a query for SQL Server to find a specific value in all tables and databases? I emphasize query not stored procedure.

Comment: How come you want to do this? Don't you know where you store your data?

Comment: I want to do this because if I forgot where my data is stored or whether I added a table in a big project or not

Comment: Tough luck. Simply search the tables, one at the time. (Can be done dynamically, with a loop.)

Comment: you are right but sometimes we don't have time for this , do you know the script for this ?

Comment: Learn how to prioritize. If you just throw tables and data into your project without knowing what you're doing, you'll have to pay sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I'll keep it in mind

Comment: Do you ever go around searching your entire house if you know you've left your keys on the kitchen counter? Don't do that with your applications either, even in testing. Take note of @jarlh 's advices and learn to set best practices! If your database grows to hundreds of GB / TB then knowing some information in advance (*table names*) can save you hours of query search time (not to mention resources).

Comment: This is the answer I posted as an answer in a Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385508/find-a-value-and-shows-me-database-table-column-primary-key-of-the-found-value/43630272#43630272

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a way.

**Option 1:**

There is a procedure called `sp_msForEachTable` that can help you. It's not really an officially documented feature and therefore not recommended to use, but it works.

```
EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ?'
```

Bear in mind it might take a while to list everything if you have a lot of tables. And if you have a reeeeally lot of tables and not so much RAM, your Management Studio might crash before finishing.

**Option 2:**

You can use system view `sys.tables` to create your SQL dynamically

```
SELECT 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + name FROM sys.tables
```

Then you can copy/paste results in another window and maybe run them in parts.

Comment: Thanks for you response

Answer (score -2):

If you know your table names:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, ...;
```

Comment: is there a loop to do this action instead of writing table1,table2,.... ?

Comment: Just share appropriate answers..and think first before posting.Read Question Carefully.

Comment: This will probably bring all activity on your server to a halt if the tables are anything more than a handful of rows each.